# Which aircraft is easier to land-- Supermarine Spitfire or North American P-51 Mustang?

Tags: landing, aviation-history, tail-dragger

Which aircraft is easier to land (without ground-looping)-- the Supermarine Spitfire or the North American P-51 Mustang?

If the answer is different depending on conditions (e.g. no-wind versus crosswind), please elaborate.  Likewise please elaborate if a particular technique (e.g. 3-point-landing versus wheel landing) should be used to obtain the best results in a given circumstance.

Points of interest-- note that the P-51's tailwheel is located well forward of the tail, giving the landing gear a "short-coupled" configuration.  Note that the Spitfire main landing gear legs were located close together (giving a narrow "track").

Comment: I feel "easier" is in the realms of opinions

Comment: This is more a matter of opinion

Comment: I agree it's opinion-based. I suggest editing to something like *What are the challenges in landing a Spitfire or P-51 Mustang?* or maybe *What makes the Spitfire or P-51 Mustang more difficult to land compared to other aircraft?*

Comment: Hmmm maybe should I ask for published recommendations (3-point versus wheel landing) on how to land a P-51 in crosswind and no-wind conditions-- or is that too broad?  As it's likely or at least possible that not all published sources give the same recommendation--

Answer (score 1):

This is more opinion based than factual. That being said I do know that the Griffon powered Spitfires were more difficult to handle in the traffic pattern due to their increased engine torque and opposite yaw effect from P-Factor of a propeller turning counterclockwise.  I know those airplanes were not popular with their pilots for that reason.  Never heard anything bad about the Merlin powered Spitfires.

Mustangs were apparently more difficult to execute good 3-point landings with and wheel landings were the recommended technique in that airplane.